# MathJax: Bottom entries in a matrix cut off

Tags: bug, mathjax

Has there been any sort of MathJax update? In this answer I see the denominators in the bottom two entries of this matrix are partially cut off. I do not remember seeing this behavior before.

[image]

I just checked and my zoom is at 100%, so it should not be a zooming issue.

[This is the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3590680/simple-reflection-of-vector-in-mathbbr2-weird-answer/3590708) and my browser is chrome version 80.0.3987.132 on Windows 10.

Edit: Changing the math renderer to common html fixes it, but it still seems this glitch should be recorded.

Comment: It's a glitch in The Matrix! The agents on closing in, run away!

Comment: Often when I see a MathJax glitch, it goes away if I re-load the page.  Your page is OK for me (Safari 13.0.5).  What I do sometimes see is the top of a big integral sign cut off.

Comment: @GEdgar That doesn't seem to resolve it for me. I tried leaving and coming back and reloading while I was still at the page, and I still see it cut off.

Comment: Right-click on the math, then under "Math Settings" > "Math Renderer", what do you have?  If you change the math renderer, does that help?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, choosing Common HTML fixes it.

Comment: What renderer did you use before changing to Common HTML?  I'm currently using HTML-CSS as the math renderer (on Chromium 79.0.3945.117), and I don't see the matrix truncation you depicted.

Comment: @hardmath When I switch it back to HTML-CSS it's cut off again.

Comment: Thanks.  I also have Fast Preview set, but I think that doesn't come into play except in editing.

Comment: @MattSamuel I also noticed a similar problem just a day or two ago, but without it involving any matrices. It was just a fairly standard one-line equation. In my case, I solved it just by adding brackets in the form of "\left(" and "\right)" in one place.